# Compress or resize image before rendering

Tags: playframework

Refer to http://www.playframework.org/community/snippets/4

Is it possible to compress/resize the Blob image before rendering it on screen?

```
public static void getPicture(long id) {
   Picture picture = Picture.findById(id);
   response.setContentTypeIfNotSet(picture.image.type());
   renderBinary(picture.image.get());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Image class in the `play.libs` package, which has a static method called resize.

The signature is

```
resize(java.io.File originalImage, java.io.File to, int w, int h)
```

You obviously need to go through extra steps to save the image to a File, to then perform the conversion, but if this is too much, you may be able to take a copy of the code and make it work with a Blob instead.

Alternatively, if there is any other third party library that works with the Blob type, then this could easily be integrated.

Comment: Note that when using this method, you may loose rotation information (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453367/is-javax-imageio-imageio-broken-it-imports-some-images-as-rotated for more on that).

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling JPEG or other compressed images, you won't save much disk/bandwidth compressing the image. For the most cases you will probably just get some bytes less which are not worth the compression cost.

For resize [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/index.html) (which is a interface for [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)) is a good option. There is a [small tutorial](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jmagick/index.php?title=Changing_The_Size_Of_An_Image) about how to resize images using JMagick.

Hope that helps